# How do I reconcile rowID from a grid with the TRUE rowID back in the MYSQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, jqgrid, rowid

I have a the current release of JQgrid  running and I have no problem searching within that grid, selecting a row, and editing it.

When I pass this upstream the PHP code shows the values for POSTed variables BUT

the ROWid posted back corresponds to the ROWid of the selected ELEMENT in the grid I edit and NOT to the

TRUE rowID of element back in the orginating table.

Consequently, I'm unsure HOW to update/delete entries based on THAT rowID.

Hows does JQgrid 'know' which row to update in the 'real table' or MUST I simply add a new column that

autoincrements and pass THAT back to use as the key for the row in the real table to update??

Don't think I need post code here… :)

Comment: one of the fields in the grid should be the primary key of the record back in the database...

Comment: darn............ schema change was hoping that jqgrid had the background 'smarts' to figure out WHICH row it had pulled data from to generate its grid..

Answer (score 0):

You question shows indirectly that you fill jqGrid in not quite correct way. One sees that you don't understand what is the "rowid".

jqGrid build grid based on the HTML table. The main information which will be placed in the table are rows of data. Rows in HTML table are `<tr>` elements which have `<td>` elements as cells. During filling of the data in the grid all `<tr>` elements will be filled inclusive the `id` attribute like

```
<tr id="1410"><td>cell for the first column<td><td>cell for the second column<td></tr>
```

It's important to understand that the current implementation of **jqGrid must have `id` attributes for every row**. The JSON or XML data which you post back from the server have to contain the `id` information (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data) about different supported formats if jqGrid input data).

So if you fill the `id` property of JSON or XML data as the ids from the database no problem which you describe will never exist. The problem exist either if you don't fill the `id` properties or fill it in the wrong way. In both cases jqGrid will don't find any information about ids and in the case it will have to generate ids of `<tr>` elements itself. Currently jqGrid uses in the case sequential numbers 1, 2, 3, ..., but it can be changed in any new version of jqGrid.

So I recommend you verify the format of data which you post back to jqGrid when you fill it. If you will have problems to find the bug you should include the full definition of the jqGrid in the text of your question and include additionally the server response (JSON or XML data). To catch exact server response you can use for example [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: I am going to alter my DB schema to include an auto-incrementing value in the FIRST column that will effectively identify the row ID. Many thanks Oleg. This was purely an oversight on my part as the initial schema design has keyed on numbers unique is a different column from rowid.

Comment: @ivanbishop: Sorry, but you misunderstand me. You don't need make any changes in the DB schema. Any *existing* id in the DB can be used. I think your problem is that you have an error in the way how you construct the JSON or XML response on the server to fill the grid. If you would edit the text of your question and include jqGrid definition and the JSON/XML data which you use in the grid I would be able to point exactly where is your error.